# How can one prove by definition that $\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{1}{x-3} = -1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> How can one prove by definition that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{1}{x-3} = -1$?

---

I began to find a $\delta$ and considered:

$$\vert \frac{1}{x-3}+1\vert \lt \epsilon.$$

I got
$\vert \frac{x-2}{x-3}\vert \lt \epsilon$ and I have to delimit $\vert \frac{1}{x-3}\vert $. Then I chose $\delta$ with $0 \lt \delta \le 1$. But I have a trouble, because if I start with:
$\vert x-2 \vert \lt 1$, then I have $-2 \lt x-3 \lt 0$.

I was thinking if I should consider instead $0\lt\delta\le2$.

Comment: Why are you starting with $|x-2|<1$?  Where exactly is your $\delta$ coming in?

Answer (score 5):

Choosing to limit $\delta$ is the right approach, but choosing to limit it to $|x - 2| < 1$ won't help you (and not for the reason you think).

It's not a problem to get $-2 < x - 3 < 0$; all this means is that $|x - 3|$ will be between $0$ and $2$. The actual problem is that you're not bounding $|x - 3|$ away from $0$. You need $|x - 3|$ not just to be non-zero, but larger than some fixed $\alpha > 0$. The issue is that, if $|x - 3|$ is really, really close to $0$, then $\frac{1}{|x - 3|}$ will be really, really large, so it will make it really, really hard to force $\frac{1}{|x - 3|}{|x - 2|}$ to be smaller than your given $\varepsilon$.

Making $\delta \le 2$ won't work either! You need a tighter bound. If you allowed for $\delta = 2$, then $x = 3$ would be allowed, and $\frac{1}{|x - 3|}$ would be undefined!

Instead, make a tighter bound on $\delta$. Force it to be less than any number less than $1$, e.g. $0.9$. If you have
$$|x - 2| < 0.9 \implies -1.9 < x - 3 < -0.1 \implies |x - 3| > 0.1 \implies \frac{1}{|x - 3|} < 10.$$
Now, $10$ is the "worst case" for the $\frac{1}{|x - 3|}$ term. From here, we have, under the assumption $|x - 2| < 0.9$,
$$\frac{1}{|x - 3|} < 10 \implies \frac{|x - 2|}{|x - 3|} < 10|x - 2|,$$
so if $|x - 2| < \frac{\varepsilon}{10}$, then we are done! In particular, we are choosing $\delta = \min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{10}, 0.9\right\}$, so that both conditions are simultaneously satisfied.

Note that, the closer to $1$ that I choose my maximum value of $\delta$, the worse this "worst case" becomes. If I had enforced $\delta \le 0.99$ instead, then I would need $|x - 2| < \frac{\varepsilon}{100}$. It honestly doesn't matter what limit I put on $\delta$, but a limit less than $1$ needed to be enforced.

Comment: You'll probably want to state somewhere that the value of $\delta$ you actually chose was $\delta=\min{(0.9,\epsilon/10)}$.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to prove is that given an $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that when $0 < |x - 2| < \delta$, $|\frac{1}{x - 3} + 1| < \epsilon$. Now you want to choose $\delta$ so that $|\frac{x - 2}{x + 3}| < \epsilon$. We can arbitrarily can require $|x - 2| < 1$; this is to determine bounds on $|x + 3|$. Then $-1 < x - 2 < 1$, which can be written as $-1 + 5 < x - 2 + 5 < 1 + 5$, or $4 < x + 3 < 6$. Since $x + 3 > 4$, we have $|\frac{x - 2}{x + 3}| < \frac{|x - 2|}{4}$. So given an $\epsilon > 0$, you would want to have $|x + 3| > 4$ and $0 < |x - 2| < 4 \epsilon$. This means that given $\epsilon > 0$, if you choose $\delta = 4 \epsilon$, when $0 < |x - 2| < \delta$, you get $|\frac{x - 2}{x + 3}| < \frac{|x - 2|}{4} < \frac{4 \epsilon}{4} = \epsilon$, which is what you want to prove.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\epsilon>0$, you want to find an $\delta$ (*in terms of* $\epsilon$) such that the following *implication* is true: 
$$
0<|x-2|<\delta\quad \textbf{implies}\quad|\frac{1}{x-3}+1|<\epsilon\tag{1}
$$

As you have observed, 
$$
\frac{1}{x-3}+1=\frac{x-2}{x-3},
$$
so (1) is the same as
$$
0<|x-2|<\delta\quad \textbf{implies}\quad\frac{|x-2|}{|x-3|}<\epsilon.\tag{2}
$$

To get $\frac{|x-2|}{|x-3|}<\epsilon$, you want $|x-2|$ small and $|x-3|$ not too small (since otherwise $\frac{1}{|x-3|}$ would be big).

- First, consider $x$ with $0<|x-2|<\frac12$, then you have $|x-3|\ge \frac12$ and thus
  $$
  \frac{|x-2|}{|x-3|}\le 2|x-2|\quad \textrm{for}\ 0<|x-2|<\frac12\tag{3}
  $$
- Now, if you let $\delta=\min(\frac{\epsilon}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, (3) tells you that for $x$ with $0<|x-2|<\delta$, 
  $$
  \frac{|x-2|}{|x-3|}\le 2|x-2|<\epsilon.
  $$